# Creating tables for clean Data

Tags: python-3.x, excel, database, grouping

let me start out by saying I have a basic understanding of python and excel. What I’m trying to do is take a CSV file with data points for voltages along side with date in mm/dd/yyyy in a separate column, and averaging the data points for each day into a chart. There’s roughly 10000 data points for the month each separated by 5 minute increments. I don’t know where to start. I also have to do this about 12 separate times so if I can just feed a program an excel file or data from notepad that would help me tremendously.

I’m a bit rusty with python but I can read it pretty well to figure out what does what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If I can do this all in excel then that would be amazing. But I would like to brush up on my coding. If someone can point me in the right direction, I’m using Jupyter notebook and excel for reference. I tried starting with just opening the file with open() but now I don’t even know where to begin. Should I install pandas? Selenium?

I tried grouping the data in excel  manually by using group. I tried opening up files in Python and creating a list of values to go through and average them. I also looked into using pivot tables to group the data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No coding needed for that. Excel pivot can solve it.

1. Bring your date column in a format excel understands as date.
   [image: SourceData]
2. Insert pivot from the range that contains your data
3. Drag the Date to lower left quadrant `rows`
4. Drag the voltage to lower right quadrant `values`
5. Change aggregation of values from `sum` to `average`

[image: pivotQuadrants]

6. The result will be this table:

[image: TheResult]